# Set variables properly while doing async programming

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a model which has a property

```
public static class CheckerClass
{
    public static bool checkFlag { get; set; }
}
```

I have a method which sets the above property

```
public async Task test()
{
    checkFlag = true;
    await SomeotherService1.Method1();
}
```

SomeotherService1.cs

```
Method1(){
  SomeotherService2.Method2(somedata);
}
```

//there are more calls to reach `Method5()`, so I cannot send a property to see if it is called from `test()` or not.

SomeotherService5.cs

```
Method5(SomeModel someData)
{
    if(checkFalg)
    {
        checkFlag = false;
        //execute methods
    }
    else
    {
        //execute some other methods
    }
}
```

I have some threads which run both `test()` and `Method()` [suppose thread1]
and some threads which only run `Method()` [suppose thread2].

When thread1 runs it sets the `checkFlag` to true and the if condition in `Method()` will execute.

But, when thread2 runs at the same time, the `checkFlag` is still true which is not correct. How do I solve this problem.

thread2 should always have `checkFlag = false;`

Comment: Can we see the full model definition that contains checkFlag? Is the class marked as static?

Comment: @Matt yes, it is static

Comment: @Matt I have edited my question. Please check it now

Comment: I can't see what you are trying to do. I really suspect you're mixing 2 concepts: Threading and OOP. I mean, if you want a property to have some value in its own context (be it a thread or whatever) i guess you should just instanciate a new instance  and run your method on that instance (or pass an object that represent some state). That way, your requirements for thread 1 and 2 are met. A static property will have 1 value at a time, regardless of the thread accessing it.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, you should synchronize access to your flag property. This can be done multiple ways, but the easiest might be a simple lock:

Create a sync field:

```
private readonly object _sync = new object();
```

and then do the check like:

```
lock(_sync)
{
    if(checkFlag)
         return;
    checkFlag = true;
}
```

**EDIT**: Rereading your question, im not sure i understand correctly what you want. Especially "thread2 should always have checkFlag = false;" and the fact that you have checkFlag as a property on a model, but you use it everywhere confuses me. Should your `Method` not just include another variable? The way you formulate your question, it doesn't seem related to a threading issue? Does

```
public async Task test(){
    await SomeotherService.Method(someData, true);
 }
```

SomeotherService.cs

```
Method(SomeModel someData, bool check = false){
    if(check ){
       //execute methods
    }
    else{
       //execute some other methods
    }
 }
```

Comment: I have edited my question, I am not directly calling `method2()` from `method1()`, so I cannot send a property in every method and check it in the last `method()`.

Comment: I want to create a variable which is set to true by some calls made by automation, and the default value should be false. if automation call sets the flag to true and at the same time another call comes in it should not have flag as true but the default value (false).

Comment: This scenario seems to me a bit messy. If I understand the problem you are trying to work through I believe the observer pattern could solve it. From the examples and discussions thus far it seems like you are trying to shoe horn in a solution. I may be wrong here. Take a look at the following link and see if that provides you with a solution. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/observer-design-pattern

Comment: You will also want to read this article on static variables and thread safety. https://odetocode.com/Articles/313.aspx   What you are trying to do is not thread safe.